# how i can send soapClient request in php

Tags: php, soapui, soap-client

how i can send request like this whit soapClient

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ext="Ext.Bo.ITransService" xmlns:ext1="Ext.Svc" xmlns:naf="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Nafis.SVC.Objects">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ext:Report>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <ext:input>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <ext1:AuIn>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <naf:Password>?</naf:Password>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <naf:UserName>?</naf:UserName>
            </ext1:AuIn>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <ext1:GroupCode>?</ext1:GroupCode>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <ext1:FromDate>?</ext1:FromDate>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <ext1:FromRefNo>?</ext1:FromRefNo>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <ext1:MerchantCode>?</ext1:MerchantCode>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <ext1:ToDate>?</ext1:ToDate>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <ext1:ToRefNo>?</ext1:ToRefNo>
         </ext:input>
      </ext:Report>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

i get this whit SoapUi but i cant send this whit SoapClient

Url :http://nafistestpublic.fanavacard.com/extsrv-svcbo/TransService.svc?wsdl

myPhpCode is =>

```
 error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    $AuIn = array("Password"=>"123","UserName"=>"neka");
    $client = new SoapClient('http://nafistestpublic.fanavacard.com/extsrv-svcbo/TransService.svc?wsdl',array('trace' => TRUE));
    $parameters = array(
        'AuIn'=> $AuIn,
        'GroupCode'=>"1453",
        'FromDate'=> "1395/05/01",
        'ToDate'=> "1395/05/03",
        "FromRefNo"=>'',
        "MerchantCode"=>'',
        "ToRefNo"=>''
    );
    $result = $client->__soapCall("Report",$parameters);
```

but i get This error

> Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [a:DeserializationFailed] The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: Error in deserializing body of request message for operation 'Report'. End element 'Body' from namespace 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' expected. Found element 'param1' from namespace ''. Line 2, position 148. in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/inkam/merchant.php:26 Stack trace: #0 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/inkam/merchant.php(26): SoapClient->__soapCall('Report', Array) #1 {main} thrown in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/inkam/merchant.php on line 26

in suoapUi its work but not work in php

Thanks a lot

Comment: check out nusoap